# EF Expression combining

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have two Lambda Expressions- one, which has many conditions combined with or, and another one, which is just a regular value check. Those two need to be combined with AND.

The problem is, that I need to combine them in a way, that first expression (the one with many OR's) is not translated as a whole seperate expression.

For example, translated query looks like this -

```
SELECT t.field1, t.field2, t.json_array_field, t.field4
FROM table AS t
WHERE t.json_array_field @> @__Format_1 OR t.json_array_field @> @__Format_2 AND t.field4 = @__value_3
```

But what i need to achieve is this -

```
SELECT t.field1, t.field2, t.json_array_field, t.field4
FROM table AS t
WHERE (t.json_array_field @> @__Format_1 OR t.json_array_field @> @__Format_2) AND t.field4 = @__value_3
```

For combining Lambda expressions with `OR` or `AND` I am using the following extension class I made:

```
    public static class ExpressionExtensions
    {
        public static Expression<Func<TInput, bool>> CombineWithAndAlso<TInput>(this Expression<Func<TInput, bool>> func1, Expression<Func<TInput, bool>> func2)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, bool>>(
                Expression.AndAlso(func1.Body, new ExpressionParameterReplacer(func2.Parameters, func1.Parameters).Visit(func2.Body)),
                func1.Parameters);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<TInput, bool>> CombineWithOr<TInput>(this Expression<Func<TInput, bool>> func1, Expression<Func<TInput, bool>> func2)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, bool>>(
                Expression.Or(func1.Body, new ExpressionParameterReplacer(func2.Parameters, func1.Parameters).Visit(func2.Body)),
                func1.Parameters);
        }

        private class ExpressionParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            private IDictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> ParameterReplacements { get; set; }

            public ExpressionParameterReplacer(IList<ParameterExpression> fromParameters, IList<ParameterExpression> toParameters)
            {
                ParameterReplacements = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
                for (int i = 0; i != fromParameters.Count && i != toParameters.Count; i++)
                {
                    ParameterReplacements.Add(fromParameters[i], toParameters[i]);
                }
            }

            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            {
                if (ParameterReplacements.TryGetValue(node, out var replacement))
                {
                    node = replacement;
                }

                return base.VisitParameter(node);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it even possible to combine two expressions in the way I described earlier, or EF just cannot do it yet?

Comment: Sure, it is easy. The `Expression` is a tree, you just need to ensure the top operator is the `&&` with the left operand the `||` `Expression` tree and the right operand the simple test `Expression`.